# How Can I Use LIKE and Equal Together in Mysql Select

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

```
include 'config.php';
$location_null = "";
$location = "%{test}%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM students WHERE location LIKE ? AND location = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $location, $location_null); 
$stmt->execute();
```

This is my mysql codes. I wanna fetch datas from database for location like session and equal variable but this way's not working.

Comment: The equals is going to cancel out the like. You'll only get results where it's exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the `AND` with an `OR` in your query to make both conditions work:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM students WHERE location LIKE ? OR location = ?');
```

Comment: Nice answer can be AND is well `SELECT * FROM students WHERE location = :values AND name LIKE ?`